# Upgrading from angular 12 to 14 causes storybook error: TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation

Tags: angular, webpack, storybook, angular-storybook

My angular 12 build is using webpack 5 to build storybook. I upgraded to angular 13 and then to 14 and suddenly the same storybook build is failing with

```
TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
```

I have tried installing webpack directly, and I have tried adding an `overrides` section for webpack to lock it at 5.75.0. Everything I've found points to conflicting webpack versions, but `npm ls webpack` returns the same output now as it did in my angular 12 build when it was working:

```
├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-angular@14.2.10
│ ├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.1402.10
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ @ngtools/webpack@14.2.10
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ babel-loader@8.2.5
│ │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ copy-webpack-plugin@11.0.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ css-loader@6.7.1
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ less-loader@11.0.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ mini-css-extract-plugin@2.6.1
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ postcss-loader@7.0.1
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ sass-loader@13.0.2
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ source-map-loader@4.0.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ stylus-loader@7.0.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ webpack-dev-middleware@5.3.3
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ webpack-dev-server@4.11.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ webpack-subresource-integrity@5.1.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ └── webpack@5.74.0
├─┬ @cypress/webpack-preprocessor@5.16.0
│ ├─┬ babel-loader@8.3.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
├─┬ @storybook/addon-essentials@6.5.14
│ └─┬ @storybook/core-common@6.5.14
│   ├─┬ fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.2
│   │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│   └─┬ webpack@4.46.0
│     └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.5
│       └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
├─┬ @storybook/angular@6.5.14
│ ├─┬ @storybook/core@6.5.14
│ │ ├─┬ @storybook/core-server@6.5.14
│ │ │ ├─┬ @storybook/builder-webpack4@6.5.14
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ css-loader@3.6.0
│ │ │ │ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ file-loader@6.2.0
│ │ │ │ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ html-webpack-plugin@4.5.2
│ │ │ │ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ postcss-loader@4.3.0
│ │ │ │ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ style-loader@1.3.0
│ │ │ │ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@4.2.3
│ │ │ │ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ url-loader@4.1.1
│ │ │ │ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3
│ │ │ │ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ webpack-filter-warnings-plugin@1.2.1
│ │ │ │ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ └─┬ webpack@4.46.0
│ │ │ │   └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.5
│ │ │ │     └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ │ │ ├─┬ @storybook/manager-webpack4@6.5.14
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ css-loader@3.6.0
│ │ │ │ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ html-webpack-plugin@4.5.2
│ │ │ │ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ style-loader@1.3.0
│ │ │ │ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@4.2.3
│ │ │ │ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3
│ │ │ │ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ └─┬ webpack@4.46.0
│ │ │ │   └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.5
│ │ │ │     └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ │ │ └─┬ webpack@4.46.0
│ │ │   └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.5
│ │ │     └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ postcss-loader@4.3.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ raw-loader@4.0.2
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ sass-loader@10.4.1
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ ts-loader@8.4.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
├─┬ @storybook/builder-webpack5@6.5.14
│ ├─┬ css-loader@5.2.7
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.2
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ html-webpack-plugin@5.5.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ style-loader@2.0.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.6
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ webpack-dev-middleware@4.3.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
├─┬ @storybook/manager-webpack5@6.5.14
│ ├─┬ @storybook/core-client@6.5.14
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ css-loader@5.2.7
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ webpack-dev-middleware@4.3.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
│ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
├─┬ ts-loader@9.4.2
│ └── webpack@5.75.0 deduped
└── webpack@5.75.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update one by one.
Example from Angular 9 to 10 from 10 to 11 and so on.
Go back to version 12 and try to update to 13 and then to 14.
For me work in this way, i had the same error because i try to upgrade version 9 to 13 direct.

Graciously, Igor R.

Comment: sorry, i hadn't clarified. i did go to 13 and then 14 individually

Comment: Ok, sorry about didnt help ):